# data time Format recognition in exported excel with xlsxwriter

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I didn't find a solution for this:

From a dataframe I generate an excel and some columns need to be in format hh:mm:ss (with no limit to 24h, for example a value can be '28:39:13'.

When generating the excel everything looks okay. But when operating with the values of the cells isn't working properly until I apply the "text to columns" option.

```
## Example code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
example_list = ["12:35:25", "", "", "", "27:36:11"]
example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('enhanced.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
example_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name='report')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['report']
total_hformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[h]:mm:ss', 'bold': False})
worksheet.set_column('A:C', 12, total_hformat)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

**Before applying "text to columns":**

[A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6 returns **correct result**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcz3b.png)

[sum(A1:A6) returns **wrong result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYver.png)

Applying "text to columns":

[text_to_columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj5wP.png)

[text_to_columns_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qag46.png)

**After applying "text to columns":**

[Everything is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp7Zb.png)

Why does this happen? How can I solve it from xlsxwriter and avoid the need of converting all the columns after exporting an excel??

Thanks.

**EDIT:  I SOLVED IT!!**
Excel has own numeric time format which is composed of a integer (days) + fraction (percentage time of the day). Example 1,25 = 30 hours.
Then we just need the time in seconds (unix format) then divide the time between the amount of seconds of a day (60*60*24). That is the value which sould be in the dataframe. When exporting with xlsxwriter, just apply the format '[h]:mm:ss' like i shown in the example above.

Comment: In the dataframe are the times in datetime format or are they strings?

Comment: They are strings. I also tried with datetime then exporting with xlsx to hh:mm:ss and the result is worse than I have actually. The goal is having the hh:mm:ss format without 24h limit. It should be '36:00:00' instead of '1 day 12:00:00'. And after that the possibility to operate with the hours in the excel file.

Comment: When I write the dataframe in datetime format, the exported excel keeps the datetime format, it doesn't change to '[h]:mm:ss'

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT: Excel has own numeric time format which is composed of a integer (days) + fraction (percentage time of the day). Example 1,25 = 30 hours. Then we just need the time in seconds (unix format) then divide the time between the amount of seconds of a day (60*60*24). That is the value which sould be in the dataframe. When exporting with xlsxwriter, just apply the format '[h]:mm:ss' like i shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be to convert the time strings to datetime objects and then set '[h]:mm:ss' as the datetime_format in [pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). However, I don't think it is possible to parse 24h+ times with [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

In which case it is probably easiest to convert the time string to an [Excel serial date](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html#). Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

example_list = ['12:35:25', '', '', '', '27:36:11']

# Convert the time string to Excel serial dates.
for i, date in enumerate(example_list):
    m = re.match('^(\d+):(\d+):([\d\.]+)$', date)

    if m:
        seconds = (int(m.group(1)) * 60 * 60 +
                   int(m.group(2)) * 60 +
                   float(m.group(3)))
        serial_date = seconds / (24 * 60 * 60)
        example_list[i] = serial_date

example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('enhanced.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

example_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name='report')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['report']
total_hformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[h]:mm:ss', 'bold': False})
worksheet.set_column('A:C', 12, total_hformat)

writer.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Apart from the for() loop the rest of the code is the same as yours. I've allowed for decimal seconds which may not be necessary.